# send JSON from JStree to MSSQL DB

Tags: javascript, html, json, asp.net-web-api2, jstree

I could be able to load data from MSSQL table to JStree through ASP.net api controllers.But I can't send JSON object to MSSQL database through ASP.net web api controllers.

below show my script code``

```
  <script>
    $(function () {
        $('#html1').jstree({
            'core': {
                'animation': 0,
                'check_callback': true,
                'data': {
                    //'url': '/Home/Nodes',
                    'type': 'POST',
                    'url': apiBaseUrl + '/api/GenNode/Nodes',
                    'data': function (node) {
                        return { 'id': node.id };
                    }
                }
            },
            "plugins": ["themes", "html_data", "ui", "crrm", "contextmenu", 'dnd', 'state'],
        }).on('rename_node.jstree', function (e, data) {

        }).on('create_node.jstree', function (e, data) {

        }).on('delete_node.jstree', function (e, data) {

        }).jstree();
    });
</script>
```

below html code

```
 <div id="html1"> </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to make Ajax call to server from your JS Tree event handlers to post data to server..

```
     }).on('rename_node.jstree', function (e, data) {
// ajax call 

        }).on('create_node.jstree', function (e, data) {
// ajax call
        }).on('delete_node.jstree', function (e, data) {
// ajax call
        }).jstree();
```

Comment: how to pass json object from JSTree from web api controllers

Comment: I'm on the same problem on creating folders and files in a database with ajax and then refreshing the page to show new data from the database in the tree. Is there a tutorial that shows how this ajax call to the server can be done? At the moment, this has left me hanging and I would appreciate it if anyone can answer. Thanks.

Comment: @naz786 tutorials are available on jstree website.